# Is "javascript:function()" a URL?

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-webview

Going through [the WebView demo](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/using-webviews.html), I noticed the following statement:

```
  mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:wave()");
```

It works, but I don't understand the syntax. Why does the "javascript:function()" work as a URL paramter to WebView.loadUrl() ?

Comment: As a fun tangent, when "javascript:" is used as a prefix in the value of "onfoo" attributes ("onclick", "onblur", etc), it's not "special" and is just treated as a statement label by JavaScript when the handler function is synthesized.

Comment: @Pointy Thanks for this piece of information. There's so much to learn... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called [Bookmarklet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet).

Here are some examples: http://www.bookmarklets.com/

Comment: All answers were excellent and very educating. Unfortunately, I can only accept one.

Comment: It is not called a Bookmarklet. A Bookmarket is when a javascript: scheme URI is stored as a bookmark in a browser so the user can run it on arbitrary pages (again, usually for the side effects rather then actually using it as a URL). This example doesn't store it in a bookmark.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, although not very far along the standards track: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-hoehrmann-javascript-scheme-03

The return value of the function should be the document to be rendered.

Comment: All that wave() function contains is the statement **document.getElementById("droid").src="android_waving.png";**, no return statement.

Comment: Since it returns nothing, there is no document to render, and the browser does nothing with the return result. The author of the code is depending on the side effects of a `javascript:` url instead of using it for the purpose the scheme was designed for.

Answer (score 1):

It is the same like `<a href="javascript:alert('test')">link text</a>`
Your browser knows that this is javascript and starts the named function.

Comment: I understand from your answer that this is a standard browser notation and not particular to WebView. Thanks for this. (sorry, I only know Javascript basics and don't have much experience with it)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is a url that defines some javascript functionality to be run within the global scope of the current page.

It is the way bookmarklets work

Comment: Thanks for making this clear with "within the global scope of the **current** page".

Answer (score 1):

if you know the notion of "overloading" something, think of it that way.  The browser is designed to examine the string that you put in the address bar (or pass as an href) and if it starts with the string literal "javascript:" it knows to execute what follows as javascript, rather than treating it as a URL.

Comment: Yes, but how does it know which HTML document to take that javascript from?

Comment: It executes javascript that comes after `javascript:` in this case it executes `wave()`. If function `wave()` is defined in currently loaded document it will execute it.